# Old data is overwritten by new data

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have this piece of code:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'programma';
// This retrieves code from the database and displays it.
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT Anaam FROM {$table_name}" );

?>
<form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'set_programma_action', 'set_programma' ); ?>
    <table>
        <?php foreach ( $retrieve_data as $retrieved_data ) { ?>
            <tr>
                <th>Programma:</th>
                <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo esc_html( $retrieved_data->Anaam ); ?></td>
                <th>
                    <button name="programma" type="submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $retrieved_data->Anaam ); ?>">Abonneer</button>
                </th>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
</form>

<?php
    // Verify nonce and save the data when user is logged in.
    // Nonce docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/using-nonces/
    if (isset( $_POST['programma'] ) && isset( $_POST['set_programma'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['set_programma'], 'set_programma_action' )) {

      $data = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'programma', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
      $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();

        if ( $current_user_id && ! empty( $data ) ) {
            update_user_meta( $current_user_id, 'programma', $data );
        }
    }
?>
```

I have page on which users can choose something, once they have chosen the thing they wished; their choice (along with the user who chose it) is saved in the database.

The problem is that once the data is saved in the database, the old data is overwritten. It would look like this:

Old data (old user choice):

[image]

New data (new user choice):

[image]

As you can see, the old data is not there anymore. It is replaced by the new choice (22nl). How can I fix this problem?

Greetings,

Johan

Comment: Thats what is supposed to happen when you do an UPDATE. Do you want to INSERT a new row?

Comment: Yeah, a new row should appear. The old one has to remain as well @RiggsFolly

Comment: `add_user_meta()`

Comment: So just: ````add_user_meta( $current_user_id, 'programma', $data );````

Comment: Your comment works. Could you write it as an answer So I can accept it? @RiggsFolly

Comment: No point, no real benefit to others

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch all of those data you can update the meta by passing an array as the third arg.

Comment: You can fetch previous data and bind it to new data,